# Debug.Print when using functions

Tags: excel, vba

```
Debug.Print UDF_Malte(Integer,Date)
```

How would you type in the Date value?

Using

```
 Debug.Print UDF_Malte(1, 8 / 2 / 2016)
```

returns an error.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Debug.Print UDF_Malte(1, "8 / 2 / 2016")
```

Comment: The text will be interpreted differently on different locales.

Comment: @GSerg - That's correct, and I expect OP to enter dates as per his/her locale. Or there's something else you are pointing to that I am missing.

Comment: No, that's all I was saying. It's just that I believe date literals are the more correct (and locale-independent) way of doing it.

Comment: @GSerg - Yup I see that in your answer, certainly a better way to handle dates.

Answer (score 0):

Date literals in VBA are enclosed in `#` and are written in en-us locale regardless of the current user's locale. You [may be more verbose](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa262556(v=vs.60).aspx) when writing date literals (`#August 2, 2017#` is okay), but the IDE will turn them to the normalized `#mm/dd/yyyy#` when you're done typing.

Given your `8/2/2016` is already in en-us (`mm/dd/yyyy`),

```
Debug.Print UDF_Malte(1, #8/2/2016#)
```